# CKEditor: PasteFromWord ignores pasteFilter

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, drupal-8

In CKEditor 4.6.2 (currently bundled in Drupal 8) ACF is disabled by default, to make sure some of the special plugins work correctly. So for the record: I do not want to enable ACF and am not able to use `allowedContent` or `disallowedContent`. I'm trying to prevent some elements to be injected on paste from Word (like `h1` and `p[styles]`).

To accomplish this, I'm trying to add these to `pasteFilter` which works perfectly on non-Word-pasted content, though when pasting from Word the `pasteFilter` seems to be ignored? Is this a bug?

So, how can I:

1. **Keep ACF disabled** - In favor of special Drupal elements
2. **Keep `pastefromword` enabled** - To detect special Word styling like indentation and lists.
3. **Add additional filtering to *all* (including from Word) pastings** - To remove some elements and attributes like `h1`, `style="font-family: Verdana"` etc...

Answer (score 4):

Handling content pasted from Word requires some serious amount of markup processing to transform it into clean, semantic content. The paste from Word filter is very specific covering many edge cases (especially with nested lists). The reason why pasting from Word has its own filter and does not reuse ACF rules is the fact that it may cause some conflicts - it is described in [this issue](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13093).

As for now there is now out-of-the-box approach to add additional filtering to content pasted from Word. However, you may utilise [`afterPasteFromWord`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterPasteFromWord) event, to filter the pasted data like:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

editor.on( 'afterPasteFromWord', function( evt ) {
    var filter = editor.activeFilter, // Use activeFilter so it reflects ACF settings.
    // var filter = new CKEDITOR.filter( 'p b' ), // Use custom new filter.
        fragment = CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml( evt.data.dataValue ),
        writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter();

    filter.applyTo( fragment );
    fragment.writeHtml( writer );
    evt.data.dataValue = writer.getHtml();
} );
```

Please see [this codepen demo](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/brLpmE?editors=1010).

You may also refer to official docs on [`CKEDITOR.filter.applyTo`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-applyTo) and [`CKEDITOR.editor.activeProperty`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-activeFilter).

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution, as a plugin:

```
// Activate the ACF filter only when pasting from Word (the opposite of the default).
// Use config.pasteFilter='semantic-content' to filter non-Word pasted content.
// Tested with ckeditor 4.8.
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('filterOnlyOnPaste', {
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.on('setData', function(evt) {
            editor.activeFilter.disabled = true;
        });
        editor.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
            editor.activeFilter.disabled = true;
        });
        editor.on('afterPasteFromWord', function(e) {
            editor.activeFilter.disabled = false;
            var filter = editor.activeFilter,
                fragment = CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml(e.data.dataValue),
                writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter();
            filter.applyTo(fragment);
            fragment.writeHtml(writer);
            e.data.dataValue = writer.getHtml();
            editor.activeFilter.disabled = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: where should I add this please? can this be added to config.js? could I see total configuration please? I'm having this issue

Comment: Put this code in `plugins/filterOnlyOnPaste/plugin.js`. Then add `filterOnlyOnPaste` to `config.extraPlugins` in `config.js`. You might also have to give CKEditor the path to the plugin in `config.js` with `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('filterOnlyOnPaste', 'WEB_PATH_TO_CKEDITOR/plugins/filterOnlyOnPaste/');`

Comment: still does not work. do I need to disable ACF? thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry, I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Some other things in my config file (which might or might not help) are: `delete config.allowedContent;`, `config.pasteFilter = 'semantic-content';`, `config.pasteFromWordPromptCleanup = false;`. I also prevent base64 images with `config.pasteFromWord_inlineImages = false;`.